# getting Win32Exception for the command or url inserted

Tags: c#

I'm doing a voice recognition system to open a bookmarked command or url. I'm facing an unknown win32exception error? Setting fixed word in the code works perfectly but not working for textfield inserted command.

Here is my code:

```
namespace Voice_Bookmarking_System
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    SpeechRecognitionEngine recEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var frm1 = new Design();
        frm1.ShowDialog(this); // make sure this instance of Form1 is visible
        label1.Text = frm1.t1;
        label2.Text = frm1.r1;
        LoadGrammars();
        StartRecognition();
    }

    private void LoadGrammars()
    {
        Choices commands = new Choices();
        commands.Add(new string[] { "'" + label1.Text + "'", "a",});
        GrammarBuilder grammarbuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
        grammarbuilder.Append(commands);
        Grammar grammar = new Grammar(grammarbuilder);
        recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(grammar);
    }

    private void StartRecognition()
    {
        recEngine.SpeechDetected += new EventHandler<SpeechDetectedEventArgs>(recEngine_SpeechDetected);
        recEngine.SpeechRecognitionRejected += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs>(recEngine_SpeechRecognitionRejected);
        recEngine.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(recEngine_SpeechRecognized);
        recEngine.RecognizeCompleted += new EventHandler<RecognizeCompletedEventArgs>(recEngine_RecognizeCompleted);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(delegate ()
        {
            recEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            recEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Single);
        });
        t1.Start();
    }

    private void recEngine_SpeechDetected(object sender, SpeechDetectedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Recognizing voice command...";
    }

    private void recEngine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result.Text.ToLower() == "'" + label1.Text + "'")
        {
            try
            {
                Process.Start("'" + label2.Text + "'");
            }
            catch (Win32Exception)
            {
                Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "'"+label2.Text+"'");
            }
        }
        switch (e.Result.Text)
        {
            case "a":
            {
                Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
                break;
            }
        }
        textBox1.Text = e.Result.Text;
    }

    private void recEngine_SpeechRecognitionRejected(object sender, SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Failure. Please try again!";
    }

    private void recEngine_RecognizeCompleted(object sender, RecognizeCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        recEngine.RecognizeAsync();
    }
  }
}
```

This line that I got my win32exception error:

```
    Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "'"+label2.Text+"'");
```

The message is shown like this:

An exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: The value of the `label2.Text` is a Text.. so what happens when you pass the `label2.Text` without the quotes.. 
`Process.Start("IExplore.exe", label2.Text);` what happens then..?

Comment: conversion ToString ? Unicode characters i mean...

Comment: what is the valie of `label2.Text`..?

Comment: http://www.google.com or winword.exe for example

Comment: then it will work.. I just tested it doing the following 
`Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "google.com");` if you know how to use variables then assign a variable to the `label2.Text` for example 
`var procToStart = label2.Text;` then do
`Process.Start("IExplore.exe", procToStart);`

Comment: Yes! It's working fine. Thank you so much. Appreciated it~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not need to wrap this around any quoted text.. if you are familiar with the 
string.Format function you could do the following

```
Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "google.com"); //works if hard coded 
var procToStart = label2.Text;
Process.Start("IExplore.exe", procToStart);//if you want to pass it by variable
```

something a little bit more advanced if you want to use `string.Format()` function

```
Process.Start("IExplore.exe",string.Format("{0}", procToStart));
```